# Не получается считать коректно кирилицу c помощью tinyxml

Tags: c++

Возникла проблема с парсером tinyxml. Не коректно считывается кирилица.
Вот код:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "./Tiny/tinyxml.h"
#include <iostream>

class Account
{
public:
    Account()
    {
        TiXmlDocument doc("111.xml");
        if(doc.LoadFile())
        {
            TiXmlElement* users = doc.FirstChildElement("users");


            
            TiXmlElement* user = users->FirstChildElement("user");
            
            std::cout << atoi(user->Attribute("id")) << std::endl;
            std::cout << user->Attribute("name");
        }

    }
};
```

Сам документ:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <user id ="1" name = "Алекс"></user>
  <user id = "2" name = "Дмитрий"></user>
</users>
```

Результат выполнения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Она считывается корректно, однако конвертировать кодировку для вывода в консоль за вас никто не будет.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать как сконвертировать ?

Comment: Я пробовал - SetConsoleCP(1251); (не работает)

Comment: На этот счет уже есть десяток вопросов...

Comment: с большой вероятностью, xml сохраненный в utf-8. Поэтому, классический костыль SetConsoleCP(1251);  не поможет (да оно и не помогает почти никогда).